# Add validation so that EditText fields cannot be null

Tags: android

So I'm trying to add validation onto my btnSubmit which will check that all editText fields have some sort of data in before storing into the array. Would anyone be able to help?

```
       if (btnSubmit == null) throw new AssertionError();
    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(editMod.getText().length()==0){
                editMod.setError("Please fill in all fields");
            }
            else if(editRoom.getText().length()==0){
                editRoom.setError("Please fill in all fields");
            }

            if (editMod.getText() != null) {
                strModule = editMod.getText().toString();
            }
            if (editRoom.getText() != null) {
                strRoomInfo = editMod.getText().toString();
            }

            inputData = strDay + " " + strTime + " " + strDuration + " " + strType + " " + strModule + " " + strRoomInfo;
            parent.addItem(inputData);
            try {
                writeFile();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Writing to file Failed.", " ");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What's editMod here? EditText or TextInputLayout?

For this current code, here is the updated version:

```
    if (btnSubmit == null) throw new AssertionError();
btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(editMod.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
            editMod.setError("Please fill in all fields");
        }
        else if(editRoom.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
            editRoom.setError("Please fill in all fields");
        }

        if (editMod.getText().toString() != null) {
            strModule = editMod.getText().toString();
        }
        if (editRoom.getText().toString() != null) {
            strRoomInfo = editMod.getText().toString();
        }

        inputData = strDay + " " + strTime + " " + strDuration + " " + strType + " " + strModule + " " + strRoomInfo;
        parent.addItem(inputData);
        try {
            writeFile();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Writing to file Failed.", " ");
        }
    }
});
}
```

Update your question and add xml code plus the rest of Java Code.

Comment: editMod editRoom are the id's of the EditText fields

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
if (TextUtils.isEmtpy(<Your EditText here>.getText().toString())) {
   //Empty
}
```